# Remote access to DOS command line from Unix

Tags: unix, command-line, dos, remote-access

I'm looking for a way to develop some Unix scripts that will connect to a DOS box (Windows server 2012) and interactively execute DOS commands.

I'm comfortable with the Unix side (I'll almost certainly use Expect), but I'm "Windows illiterate" and am unable to find anything about connecting to Windows's DOS command line in this fashion. Is this even possible to do?

(FWIW, this is to enable us to control Tableau Server using its 'tabcmd' DOS command suite from our existing Linux environment.)

**UPDATE 1**:
I think another way of asking the question is: does Windows provide anything that is the equivalent of the Unix "remote shell", accessible from Unix?

Comment: Perhaps `telnet` or some modern equivalent of `telnet`?

Comment: @merlin2011 Can one telnet *to* Windows, and reach a DOS command line? (I've only seen telnet et al. used to connect *from* Windows *to* a Unix-like box.)

Comment: Yes, Windows can be used as a telnet server. I am not sure if the command set is exactly the same as DOS, but I would guess it gets close.

Comment: I've set up an `ssh` server under Cygwin on a Windows system. I can connect to the Windows system, which gives me a bash shell. From there, I can invoke the `command` (or is it `cmd`?) to get a DOS-like command line interface. I certainly *hope* this isn't the most straightforward way to do it. You could probably set up a non-Cygwin ssh server of some sort.

Answer (score 1):

There are no built-in tools to do this, although [PsExec](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx) is a utility that can almost do what you want.  PsTools are not a built-in, but are hosted on Technet. Some things to keep in mind:

- PsExec works by actually remotely copying a file over to the Windows System32 folder (copying is one thing that is builtin ;)
- Windows uses Kerberos for authentication.  This depends on the computer you are running the command from being on the same Active Directory as the computer you want to control, with access set up from that side.  Linux can use kerberos through third-party AD integration tools (like [Quest Authentication Services](http://software.dell.com/landing/114/?gclid=CjwKEAjw3sKpBRDJ7rDqzsyuhDASJACZAikibIClXtc548G2utUQ6wa000GK5plgDEK1yKXnRhyPcxoC81rw_wcB), a commercial product), or also [Centrify](http://www.centrify.com/products/server-suite/system-catalog/red-hat-enterprise-linux/) but there are no built-in tools that do it.
- Psexec is not encrypted, meaning if you send commands containing sensitive data, they can be seen (though not the authentication part of it).
- PsExec is obviously still a Windows utility.  I have been able to get it to work using Wine, but only for a local account and after some tweaking with matching hostnames and stuff.  It's possible that if you have authenticated using QAS or Centrify that your wine command will somehow pick it up, but I haven't tested it; I don't work where we use AD anymore.

Maybe the biggest problem is the difference of philosophy between the two communities.  Windows doesn't use command line execution very often for remote administration.  There is more focus on using your local utilities on a remote system (i.e., you can load a remote registry hive from RegEdit or browse the file system of a remote system using your local Windows Explorer program).

Overall, I think Keith's solution is actually the best, and the most straightforward.